# Intent action error when plug headset on samsung galaxy s3?

Tags: android, android-intent, action, samsung-mobile

I run app on samsung galaxy s3. I get intent action VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION(action the VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION is registered before) when I plug headset in.

That is not my expectance.

P/S: only happend on Samsung galaxy S III.

Any ideal for that problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *That's not a bug, but a feature.*

I don't know if that is a common feature for all Android devices, but Samsung devices have *"volume adjustment"* function. That's, if the volume is higher than certain threshold, it will be automatically adjusted to a lower level when a headset is plugged in.